# Zebra striping a table with hidden rows using CSS3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got a table

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr style="display: none;"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr style="display: none;"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 </table>
```

I'm trying to set the table striping to use nth-child selectors but just can't seem to crack it.

```
 table #mytable tr[@display=block]:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #000;  
 }
 table #mytable tr[@display=block]:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #FFF;
 }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm close ... can't quite seem to crack it.

anyone pass along a clue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's as close as you're going to get. Note that you can't make the `nth-child` count only displayed rows; `nth-child` will take the *n*th child element no matter what, not the *nth* child that matches a given selector. If you want some rows to be missing and not affect the zebra-striping, you will have to remove them from the table entirely, either through the DOM or on the server side.

```css
#mytable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #000;
}

#mytable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here are the fixes that I made:

```
 table #mytable tr[@display=block]:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #000;  
 }
```

There's no need to specify an ancestor selector for an `id` based selector; there is only ever one element that will match `#table`, so you're just adding extra code by adding the `table` in.

```
 #mytable tr[@display=block]:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #000;  
 }
```

Now, `[@display=block]` would match elements which had an attribute `display` set to block, such as `<tr display=block>`. Display isn't a valid HTML attribute; what you seem to be trying to do is to have the selector match on the style of the element, but you can't do that in CSS, since the browser needs to apply the styles from the CSS before it can figure that out, which it's in the process of doing when it's applying this selector. So, you won't be able to select on whether table rows are displayed. Since `nth-child` can only take the *n*th child no matter what, not *n*th with some attribute, we're going to have to give up on this part of the CSS. There is also `nth-of-type`, which selects the *n*th child of the same element type, but that's all you can do.

```
 #mytable tr:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #000;  
 }
```

And there you have it.

Comment: thanks.  Since I'm looping through all the rows in the table using prototype and hiding / unhiding based on a filter condition in one of the cells, would it be possible to add a class to all rows that weren't hidden, and to an NTH-CHILD or NTH-OF-TYPE striping based on that class?  tr .visible_row:nth-child(odd)   ?

Comment: or even just:

.visible_row:nth-child(odd) { #000; }

Comment: @Alex `:nth-child` counts *all* children of the parent element, regardless of whether it matches any preceding selectors. Remember, putting two selectors together with no space in between means to match any elements which match the first *and* match the second. So if the second row is invisible, `.visible_row:nth-child(even)` won't match the second row, and you'll see the first and third rows styled in the odd color, even though the second row is hidden. If that's the effect you're going for, it works, but you probably want the zebra stripes to only apply to visible rows, which is impossible.

Comment: In order to make the zebra stripes apply only to visible rows, you'll need to actually remove the invisible ones from the table. If you're using Prototype, you probably want to use `Element.remove()` to remove the elements from the table entirely, and then insert them again later when you need them.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using JQuery to change the visibility of rows you can apply the following function to the table to add an `.odd` class where appropriate. Call it each time the rows visible is different.

```
        function updateStriping(jquerySelector){
            $(jquerySelector).each(function(index, row){
                $(row).removeClass('odd');
                if (index%2==1){ //odd row
                    $(row).addClass('odd');
                }
            });
        }
```

And for the css simply do

```
table#tableid tr.visible.odd{
    background-color: #EFF3FE;
}
```

Comment: why tr.visible.odd and not just tr.odd ?

Comment: Because the index starts at 0, to get the actual odd row, you should change index%2==1 to index%2==0

Comment: To select the visible rows for the function, use the `:visible` selector, e.g. `$("table#tableid  > tbody > tr:visible")`.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem:

`selector:not(.hidden):nth-child(even)` selects elements that havent `.hidden` class and **also** are even. **But we need** to select **subset of even elements** from the **set of elements without .hidden class**. Put differently in case of `selector:not(.hidden):nth-child(even)` part `:nth-child(even)` will ignore `:not(.hidden)` part and acts independently, but not select even from visible. By default `nth-child` cant ignore hidden rows, cause these rows are still in the DOM.

## Solution 1 (works)

**Dont hide** the rows of the table, but **remove them altogether**. Save an array of references to DOM elements of table rows (initial state). And on filter action - cycle through this array, and depending on the filtering conditions, call the `append` method for the table or `remove` for the row

instead of

```
    if (condition) {
      row.classList.add('visible')
    } else {
      row.classList.add('hidden')
    }
```

do

```
// partically pseudo code
const rows = Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll<HTMLTableRowElement>('tr'));
onClickOneOf(filterAction, (event) => {
  // ...some your stuff
  for (const row of rows) {
    if (condition) {
      tbody.appendChild(row);
    } else {
      row.remove();
    }
  }
});
```

now `nth-child` will work correctly

## Solution 2 (partially supported yet in some browsers but so cool)

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nth-child-of-s/#zebra-striping-revisited

A classic example where `:nth-child()` is used - when creating zebra-striped table. By default, this can be approached as follows:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

This works for **static** tables, but it becomes problematic when you start to **dynamically filter** the table contents.

To fix this, we can leverage `:nth-child(An+B [of S]?)` by excluding the hidden rows from the An+B logic:

```
tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden-class or other...)) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can't Zebra stripe a table with hidden rows using CSS3 you can do it with JavaScript. Here is how:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var k = 0;
    for (var j = 0, row; row = table.rows[j]; j++) {
        if (!(row.style.display === "none")) {
            if (k % 2) {
                row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(242,252,244,0.4)";
            } else {
                row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (row.style.display === "none") continue; row.style.backgroundColor = (k % 2) ? "gray" : "white"; k++`

Answer (score 1):

For a jquery way, you could use this function which iterates through the rows in your table, checking the visbility of the row and (re)setting a class for visible odd rows.

```
    function updateStriping(jquerySelector) {
        var count = 0;
        $(jquerySelector).each(function (index, row) {
            $(row).removeClass('odd');
            if ($(row).is(":visible")) {
                if (count % 2 == 1) { //odd row
                    $(row).addClass('odd');
                }
                count++;
            }            
        });
    }
```

Use css to set a background for odd rows.

```
#mytable tr.odd { background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
```

Then you can call this zebra-striper whenever by using:

```
updateStriping("#mytable tr");
```

Comment: This worked for me, along with one edit. I needed to specifically inventory what was visible in a different way for my application. Here's what worked for me: ```function updateStriping(jquerySelector){

   var visibleItems = []; 

  $(jquerySelector).each(function(){
   if( $(this).is(":visible") ) {
    visibleItems.push(this);
   }
  });

  $('.odd').removeClass('odd');
  $(visibleItems).each(function(index, row){
   if (index%2==1){ //odd row
    $(row).addClass('odd');
   }
   else {
    // something
   }
  });
}```
Sorry about the jumbled code.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a sort of solution but it's reliant on the fact that the table can only ever have a maximum number of hidden rows and comes with the downside of requiring 2 additional CSS rules for each possible hidden row. The principle is that, after each hidden row, you switch the `background-color` of the odd and even rows around.

Here's a quick example with just 3 hidden rows and the necessary CSS for up to 4 of them. You can already see how unwieldy the CSS can become but, still, someone may find some use for it:

```css
table{
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-spacing:1px;
  width:100%;
}
td{
  padding:20px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
  background:#999;
}
tr:nth-child(even)>td{
  background:#000;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]{
  display:none;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
  background:#000;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(even)>td{
  background:#999;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
  background:#999;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(even)>td{
  background:#000;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
  background:#000;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(even)>td{
  background:#999;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
  background:#999;
}
tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr[data-hidden=true]~tr:nth-child(even)>td{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-hidden="true"><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-hidden="true"><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr data-hidden="true"><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So much easier in JS, but that gets voted down here it seems

Answer (score 1):

in jquery ..

```
var odd = true; 
$('table tr:visible').each(function() {   
  $(this).removeClass('odd even').addClass(odd?'odd':'even'); 
  odd=!odd 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fake the zebra stripes if you apply a vertically repeating gradient on the parent table, positioned exactly to match the rows' height (the rows would have to be transparent). That way the table won't care if anything's hidden, it will repeat no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone tries to do something like me, where I have alternating hidden and visible rows, you can do this:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(4n + 1) {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

This will get every 4th element starting with the 1st one, and allows you to maintain striping with hidden rows between each visible row.

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: Yeah, I continue to use this pattern @mplungjan! If every visible row also has a hidden row it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2022 version of a javascript version

```js
let cnt = 0;
document.querySelectorAll("#mytable tbody tr").forEach(tr => {
  cnt += tr.hidden ? 0 : 1;
  tr.classList.toggle("odd",cnt%2===0); 
});
```

```css
.odd { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
<thead><tr><th>Num</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr hidden><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

I add in css:

```
tr[style="display: table-row;"]:nth-child(even) {
      background-color:  #f3f6fa;  
}
```

and on create tr add in tag

```
style="display: table-row;"
```

Answer (score -2):

Jquery codes for zebra color in html table

```
$("#mytabletr:odd").addClass('oddRow');
$("#mytabletr:even").addClass('evenEven');
```

And CSS you can do

```
.oddRow{background:#E3E5E6;color:black}
.evenRow{background:#FFFFFF;color:black}
```