# LESS (CSS) selector for even tr with not class .hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, less

I am working on collapse-able tables. I am trying to change background for even `tr` but I don't calculate hidden tr which have .hide class.

Issue: suppose I have two hidden `tr` by applying

```
:nth-of-type(even) // even = 2
{
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
```

changes background of every even `tr`. This cause two visible `tr` with same color. While I need stripped functionality. I don't want this selector apply on those hidden `tr` with class `.hide`. So that there would be no two adjustment `tr` with same background. As shown in screen shot.

**[Fiddle with Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/ps7Lfvgu/)**

[image]

I have tried following but not successful.

```
tr:not(.hide)
{
    &:nth-of-type(even)
    {
      background: #F5F5F5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change _nth-of-type(even)_ to _nth-of-type(2n)_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zebra striping a table with hidden rows using CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773890/zebra-striping-a-table-with-hidden-rows-using-css3)

Comment: @MarioAraque this didn't fixed my problem

Comment: are you willing to change markup? I know a pure css solution, but you cannot use tr's for rows.

Comment: @AamirShahzad can you make a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/pen/)?

Comment: @Vucko http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/ps7Lfvgu/ here is the fiddle i have updated the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in pure css.

Solved a similar issue iterating table and dynamically adding odd/even css rules to each row.

Suppose this tab

```
<table id="theTab">
  <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

With the following JS

```
var classToggle = false;

$("#theTab tr:not(.hidden)").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(classToggle ? "odd" : "even");
    classToggle = !classToggle;
});
```

It's a JQuery based solution, but works fine and doesn't require any table modification (you can use anything instead of .hidden class selector..)

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ck0dcvv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in similar situation. nth-of-type works only with different tag names.

HTML

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="row">...</row>
   <aside><div class="row">...</row></aside>
   <div class="row">...</row>
   <div class="row">...</row>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {display:table}
aside {display:none;}
.table .row:nth-of-type(odd) { background: pink; }
```

Comment: then use JS to assign odd/even row classes