# target first, even/odd and last element with class, without wrapper, among other elements (nth-of-class behaviour) :)

Tags: css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="elementWrapper">
  <div>1. Element</div>
  <div>2. Element</div>
  <div>3. Element</div>
  <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">5. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div>9. Element</div>
  <div>10. Element</div>
  <div>11. Element</div>
</div>
```

There can be a unknown number of multiple elements before and after, and I have no possibility to add a "wrapping" div around the elements with the class="alternate". (where everything would be fine).

I would like to give the first .alternate Element a border top, the last .alternate Element a border bottom. And all .alternate elements should have a different background color for each row (even/odd).

I've tried it in different ways, and I know that nth-of-type and nth-child won't work, because there is no wrapping div around my .alternate elements, and so it can't work because all Elements are counted for even/odd and so on.

So I made a pen with the problem and possible Solutions:

http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/RpyyOo

I would like to ask you, what the best way could be -without changing the structure-. Is there a working css only solution?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

For the first question (adding `border-top` to the first `.alternate` element and `border-bottom` to the last `.alternate` element), you can achieve this by adding `border-top` alone to:

- the first `.alternate` element that immediately follows an element that does [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) have the `.alternate` class, and,
- *also* to the first element that does not have the `.alternate` class that immediately follows an element that does.

In the case that there are no elements before the first `.alternate` element, you will also need to add `border-top` to the `.alternate` element that is also the `:first-child` and, in the case that there are no elements after the last `.alternate`, you will need to add `border-bottom` to the `.alternate` element that is also the `:last-child`.

For the second question on "zebra striping" the `.alternate` elements, assuming it's irrelevant whether the odd or even elements have the alternate `background`, you can achieve that with a simple `:nth-of-type()` (or `:nth-child()`) pseudo-class. However, if you require the first `.alternate` element to always have the same `background` regardless of the number of elements that precede it, you will need to resort to JavaScript - it is *possible* with CSS alone but requires a *ridiculous* number of selectors (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892714/4768433) as an example).

```js
(function(){
  var wrappers=document.querySelectorAll(".elementWrapper"),
      x=wrappers.length,
      divs,y,alt;
  while(x--){
    divs=wrappers[x].querySelectorAll(".alternate");
    y=divs.length;
    alt=!(y%2);
    while(y--)
      divs[y].classList.add((alt=!alt)?"odd":"even");
  }
})();
/** JQuery **/
//$('.alternate:odd').addClass('odd')
//$('.alternate:even').addClass('even');
```

```css
.elementWrapper>div:not(.alternate)+div.alternate,
.elementWrapper>div.alternate+div:not(.alternate),
.elementWrapper>div.alternate:first-child{
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}
.elementWrapper>div.alternate:last-child{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.elementWrapper>div.alternate.odd{
  background:#ccc;
}
.elementWrapper>div.alternate.even{
  background:#eee;
}

/** Uncomment below for CSS-only zebra-striping **/
/*.elementWrapper>div.alternate:nth-of-type(odd){
  background:#ccc;
}
.elementWrapper>div.alternate:nth-of-type(even){
  background:#eee;
}*/

/** "housekeeping" **/.elementWrapper{background:#fff;color:#000;margin:0 0 20px;}.elementWrapper>div{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:5px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;}
```

```html
<div class="elementWrapper">
  <div>1. Element</div>
  <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">5. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div>9. Element</div>
</div>
<div class="elementWrapper">
  <div>1. Element</div>
  <div>2. Element</div>
  <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks nice, thanks. But one addition. If there are no elements before or after Elements with class alternate, the line wouldn't work. I think that would be the solution: http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/aJGjZw Maybe you could change your answer :)

Comment: Okay, another problem. Even / Odd is not working like expected. Because it targets all elements in .elementWrapper not only .alternate. Please see here: http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/GWdXjJ

Comment: See the caveat in my answer regarding that: "*assuming it's irrelevant whether the odd or even elements have the alternate `background`*". However, if you give me a few minutes, I believe I can come up with a solution so that the first `.alternate` element will always have the same `background`, regardless of the number of elements that precede it.

Comment: That would be great, you have all time you need. :)

Comment: I may have spoken to soon! I assume the number of `.alternate` elements will be variable? Is there a maximum number that there can ever be?

Comment: You're right, the number is variable, and there is no maximum number. It can only be one element but also there can be 20 elements. I think I have to use $('.alternate:even').addClass('even'); for even and odd.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, under those conditions, JavaScript is going to be the best solution for ensuring the first `.alternate` element is always the same colour, no matter the number of elements that precedes it. I've updated my answer with the necessary JS.

Comment: @Shaggy Great answer . I have added another answer targeting a particular case, where it is possible to use only CSS for the zebra style

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Shaggy's answer, using `:not` & `nth-of-type` selectors, you can render what is required in pure css.

Refer code:

```css
.elementWrapper div:not(.alternate)+div.alternate,
.elementWrapper div.alternate+div:not(.alternate) {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.elementWrapper div.alternate:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: green;
}

.elementWrapper div.alternate:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementWrapper">
  <div>1. Element</div>
  <div>2. Element</div>
  <div>3. Element</div>
  <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div class="alternate">5. Element with spec. Class</div>
  <div>9. Element</div>
  <div>10. Element</div>
  <div>11. Element</div>
</div>
```

As pointed out by the OP, if there are no `div` prior or after `.alternate` elements, the above solution won't work. The usage of `first-child` and `last-child` would be preferred then.

```
/* if there are no elements before .alternate */
.elementWrapper > div.alternate:first-child{
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

/* if there are no elements after .alternate */
.elementWrapper > div.alternate:last-child{
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: That looks nice, thanks. But one addition. If there are no elements before or after Elements with class alternate, the line wouldn't work. I think that would be the solution: http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/aJGjZw Maybe you could change your answer :)

Comment: Modified my answer. :)

Comment: How does this differ from my solution?

Comment: Okay, another problem. Even / Odd is not working like expected. Because it targets all elements in .elementWrapper not only .alternate. Please see here: http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/GWdXjJ

Answer (score 1):

If your .alternate elements concentrate in one region (that is , they are all together) you can get the zebra styling with these styles:

```css
.alternate {
  background: gray;
}

div:nth-of-type(odd):not(.alternate)+div.alternate~div.alternate:nth-of-type(even),
div:nth-of-type(odd):not(.alternate)+.alternate:nth-of-type(even),
div:nth-of-type(even):not(.alternate)+div.alternate~div.alternate:nth-of-type(odd),
div:nth-of-type(even):not(.alternate)+.alternate:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="elementWrapper">
      <div>1. Element</div>
      <div>2. Element</div>
      <div>3. Element</div>
      <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">5. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div>9. Element</div>
      <div>10. Element</div>
      <div>11. Element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="elementWrapper">
      <div>1. Element</div>
      <div>2. Element</div>
      <div>3. Element</div>
      <div>4. Element</div>
      <div class="alternate">1. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">2. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">3. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">4. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div class="alternate">5. Element with spec. Class</div>
      <div>10. Element</div>
      <div>11. Element</div>
      <div>12. Element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice :) That's the route I was going too but dismissed it as being overly complex. I suggest updating your answer to address the borders as well, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the selectors for the first rule to just `div.alternate`.

Comment: Thank you ! I have edited the snippet following  your suggestion. I didn't thought my answer as being complete, rather as a complement to you answer, that covered well the borders issue